# Suddenly getting "Server refused our key" error on amazon linux for ec2-user

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, amazon-ec2

Today **all of a sudden** I am not able to SSH into my AWS linux instance using **ec2-user** as username.

I was able to do it yesterday.

I have searched for this and found that all things are in place, Security group, Key etc.

Getting this error.

`login as: ec2-user
Server refused our key
ec2-user@XX.XX.XX.XXX's password:`

I am confident that I am using the correct username, private key and IP-address.

**FYI:** The server allows password authentication as well, because we have one user per domain. That helps us to provide restricted access to developers who is managing specific websites.

I am using windows 7 and putty tool to connect to server.

I have also tried [**this**](http://readystate4.com/2013/04/09/aws-gaining-ssh-access-to-an-ec2-instance-you-lost-access-to/) and [**this**](https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-access-ec2-instance-in-case-of-loss-of-pem-file/), but getting same error. Seems my problem is different as I have not lost the key.

Since this is the root user. How can I recover access?

Comment: Start to run ssh with `-vvv` to get additional information. It usually gives a clue as to what the problem might be.

Comment: Have you broken the key on your side or just use incorrect filename of the key?

Comment: @Magnus: I am not sure about how to use `-vvv` in putty. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Putnik: No I haven't broken the key and I am sure that I am using the correct filename.

Comment: Just add it as an argument to the ssh command. Like 'ssh -vvv user@server'

Comment: @Magnus: In putty there is no terminal, so I cannot do that.

Comment: Aha, missed that you were using putty. Try enabling the session log under `Session` -> `Logging`.

Comment: @Magnus: I enabled logging in putty. It logs same error as mentioned in my question. i.e. `login as: ec2-user
Server refused our key
ec2-user@XX.XX.XX.XXX's password:` Do I need to choose any specific options under logging?

Comment: If you can, check the access right of the `~/.ssh` directory and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server. They should be `700` and `600` and owned by `ec2-user`.

Comment: Also check `/var/log/auth.log` for clues on the server

Comment: @Magnus: Provided `700` to `~/.ssh` and `600` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` but still getting same error. And there is no such file `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: @Magnus: My bad, my home folder was mounted on another EBS volume and I was trying every solution on root volume. Now I resolved the issue. Thanks a ton for your guidance.

Comment: @AmolChakane I am facing same issue since yesterday, And the only change I did, I changed the permission of /home/centos since I wanted to view some files inside .aws directoty. Now I want to revert those permissions, since I am not able to login using putty, so how Can I change the permission of this directory. I am not able to do this using FileZilla also.

Comment: @AndroidDev Check the comments, Magnus' comment dated Aug 18 '17 at 13:31 helped me.